# who to contact about issues with geoserver plugin for qgis

Tags: qgis, geoserver, boundless-suite

I have a project in QGIS that I am trying to publish using GeoServer via the plugin.

When I try and publish a layer I get:

```
global name 'provider' is not defined Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/rful011/.qgis2/python/plugins/opengeo/gui/explorer.py", line 118, in run command(*params) 
File "/Users/rful011/.qgis2/python/plugins/opengeo/gui/confirm.py", line 18, in publishLayer catalog.publishLayer(layer, workspace, overwrite, name) 
File "/Users/rful011/.qgis2/python/plugins/opengeo/qgis/catalog.py", line 379, in publishLayer self.upload(layer, workspace, overwrite, title) 
File "/Users/rful011/.qgis2/python/plugins/opengeo/qgis/catalog.py", line 245, in upload self._publishExisting(layer, workspace, overwrite) 
File "/Users/rful011/.qgis2/python/plugins/opengeo/qgis/catalog.py", line 171, in _publishExisting uri = QgsDataSourceURI(provider.dataSourceUri()) 
     NameError: global name 'provider' is not defined
```

I have looked at the plugin code and can not find any references to ‘provider’ before the fateful reference that fails.

Any ideas what is wrong?  I am aware that this plugin is labeled as experimental but it is unclear who I should contact.  I have tried to contact boundlessgeo without response and posted to the geoserver mailing list, again without any resolution.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? I can't find a Geoserver plugin.

Comment: I belive that you should open an issue on [their tracker](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite-qgis-plugin/issues), since the plugin page links to it with the tittle, 'support'

Comment: if you want to put that in as an answer I'll accept it.  I was looking for a tracker on the boundlessgeo site.  I'll log the issue.  Andre -- it is call opengeo plugin -- my bad!

Comment: I can't find that in the official qgis plugin repository either. But Devdatta seems to know it.

Comment: @AndreJoost: It is not present in the official plugin repository. More information is available here: http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Docs Page](http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/intro.html) for the OpenGeo Suite QGIS plugin , has a link titled Support, which leads to the [Issue tracker on the github reprository](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite-qgis-plugin/issues).

I suggest that you open a [new Issue](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite-qgis-plugin/issues/new) on the Issue Tracker for this Problem.